# Como obedecer ao Open/Closed principle nessa situação?

Tags: .net, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software

Estou com uma situação que a solução que eu identifiquei claramente viola o Open/Closed principle e eu gostaria de encontrar uma solução melhor que não violasse esse princípio. Óbvio que a minha preocupação não é simplesmente "obedecer o princípio", mas sim construir um código que seja de manutenção mais fácil posteriormente.

O cenário é basicamente o seguinte: temos um programa codificado em Windows Forms e precisamos implementar a execução de tarefas periódicas. O significado disso é basicamente o seguinte: queremos produzir a habilidade de que de acordo com um *critério* de cada tarefa, o sistema em determinado dia apresente uma janela ao usuário perguntando se ele quer fazer ou não, dando inclusive a possibilidade de adiar para a próxima vez que abrir o sistema.

A solução que eu encontrei, inclusive sendo a mais simples foi: criar uma enumeração `EPeriodicTasks` que contem uma lista das tarefas que o sistema implementa. Também pensei em criar uma enumeração `EPeriodicTaskStatus` com valores `Completed`, `Delayed` e `Canceled`. Após isso, criar então uma classe: `PeriodicTaskLog` que registra a informação das execuções. Ela simplesmente tem propriedades `PeriodicTask` do tipo `EPeriodicTasks`, `DateExecution` do tipo `DateTime`, `ExecutionStatus` do tipo `EPeriodicTaskStatus`.

Finalmente, implemento um serviço `PeriodicTaskService` que contem um método: `RunPeriodicTasks` que é executado sempre que o programa inicia.

Essa classe então possui para cada `PeriodicTask` dois métodos: um método de verificação, que implementa o critério pra ver se naquele dia precisa executar essa tarefa. Entre outras coisas, esse método verifica se já foi realizada naquele dia consultando os `PeriodicTaskLogs`. O segundo método é a execução em si, que pode simplesmente abrir outra janela do programa, ou simplesmente fazer algo em background.

O problema dessa solução é:  ela claramente viola o Open/Closed principle, junta muita responsabilidade na classe `PeriodicTaskService` e torna a manutenção dificil. Para adicionar uma `PeriodicTask` é necessário ir lá e mudar essa classe, e se muitas são criadas conforme o programa evolui de acordo com os requerimentos, essa classe vai ficar intratável.

Isso tudo tem uma solução óbvia e muito boa: cada periodic task ter sua própria classe, encapsulando a lógica de verificação se deve executar, e junto com a verificação a lógica em si.

O problema disso é o seguinte: cada periodic task precisa ser relacionada a um único valor da enumeração, para sermos capazes no log de identificar qual é qual. Eu posso associar um valor de enumeração a um objeto, mas não a u ma classe, já que a classe é só o modelo do objeto, não tendo valores proprios. Eu até poderia implementar um membro estático pra isso, mas parece gambiarra.

Como eu posso melhorar minha solução para obedecer o Open/Closed principle e também o Single Responsability Principle? Como eu posso resolver esse impasse e melhorar essa modelagem?

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Leonardo, recomendo você resolver seu problema usando o Rules Pattern.

Com isso, você terá uma responsabilidade única para cada tipo de tarefa que você irá fazer e também respeitará o Open/Closed.

Tem um exemplo de como usar o Rules Pattern:

public class RulesDiscountCalculator : IDiscountCalculator
{
    List _rules = new List();

```
public RulesDiscountCalculator()
{
    _rules.Add(new BirthdayDiscountRule());
    _rules.Add(new SeniorDiscountRule());
    _rules.Add(new VeteranDiscountRule());
    _rules.Add(new LoyalCustomerRule(1, 0.10m));
    _rules.Add(new LoyalCustomerRule(5, 0.12m));
    _rules.Add(new LoyalCustomerRule(10, 0.20m));
    _rules.Add(new NewCustomerRule());
}

public decimal CalculateDiscountPercentage(Customer customer)
{
    decimal discount = 0;

    foreach (var rule in _rules)
    {
        discount = Math.Max(rule.CalculateCustomerDiscount(customer), discount);
    }

    return discount;
}
```

}

Para explicação do exemplo veja:

http://www.michael-whelan.net/rules-design-pattern/

Abc!

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/104308)

Comment: Fiz a correção conforme sugerido. Grato.